# Tensorflow 2.4.1 and R 4.1.1 conflict in Anaconda

Tags: r, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, conda

Is it possible to install both the latest versions of Tensorflow (2.4.1 as of 8/2021) and R (4.1.1) in Anaconda?

I'm trying to create a Docker image using the Jupyter Spark base image that has both of these. A minimal dockerfile to do this is

```
FROM jupyter/pyspark-notebook:notebook-6.4.2

USER root

ENV R_LIBS_USER $SPARK_HOME/R/lib
RUN fix-permissions $R_LIBS_USER

USER $NB_UID

RUN mamba install --quiet --yes \
    'tensorflow=2.4.1' \
    'r-base=4.1.1'
```

Running this with `docker build . -f "minimal.dockerfile" -t minimal:latest` results in an error:

```
 => [internal] load build definition from minimal.dockerfile                       0.1s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 426B                                               0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                  0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                    0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/jupyter/pyspark-notebook:notebook-6.4.  3.0s 
 => [auth] jupyter/pyspark-notebook:pull token for registry-1.docker.io            0.0s 
 => [1/3] FROM docker.io/jupyter/pyspark-notebook:notebook-6.4.2@sha256:a9a92d02f  0.0s 
 => CACHED [2/3] RUN fix-permissions /usr/local/spark/R/lib                        0.0s 
 => ERROR [3/3] RUN mamba install --quiet --yes     'tensorflow=2.4.1'     'r-ba  33.8s 
------
 > [3/3] RUN mamba install --quiet --yes     'tensorflow=2.4.1'     'r-base=4.1.1':     
#7 33.19 Encountered problems while solving:
#7 33.19   - package arrow-cpp-5.0.0-py39he92c077_3_cpu requires libprotobuf >=3.16.0,<3.17.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed
#7 33.19 
------
executor failed running [/bin/bash -o pipefail -c mamba install --quiet --yes     'tensorflow=2.4.1'     'r-base=4.1.1']: exit code: 1
```

If I run just `mamba install tensorflow=2.4.1`, I can see that it downgrades arrow-cpp and libprotobuf, among others. Is there a way to override this behaviour?

Other things I've tried:

- If I run `mamba install tensorflow` followed by `mamba install r-base`, I get the same error as above
- If I run `mamba install r-base` followed by `mamba install tensorflow`, I end up with R 3.6, not 4.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to install everything in a single environment. Create a Python environment and create an R environment, and make sure they each have their respective kernel packages (`ipykernel`, `r-irkernel`) so that they can be used in Jupyter.

Comment: Ok, but I actually do want them installed together. Note that there is an [R interface to Tensorflow](https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow).

Comment: The R interface (which is packaged under `r-tensorflow`) works through reticulate and relies on Python TensorFlow being installed in a separate environment.